# check headers sent by file_get_contents

Tags: php, request-headers

I am trying to send headers using file_get_context:

example.php

```
$opts = array(
          'http'=>array(
            'method'=>"GET",
            'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
                      "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
          )
        );

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$response = file_get_contents($request_url, false, $context);
```

How do i check if example.php sent the headers? I tried using get_headers('example.php') at request_url.php or headers_sent() at 'example.php'. Any other suggestions to check the headers sent by file_get_contents()

Comment: Specify a [`proxy`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) in your context options and use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) as that proxy to capture the traffic.

Comment: HTTP request header fields are in `$_SERVER` and begin with `HTTP_`.

Comment: @Gumbo: You have to be the server at `$request_url` to see those.

Comment: @Jon “I tried using get_headers('example.php') at request_url.php […]”

Comment: @Gumbo: Ouch. Mindblock. :)

Comment: `request_url.php` should have access to `HTTP_` $_SERVER values, specifically `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` and `$_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']` (raw cookie values).

Comment: $_server worked. Thanks!

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the headers to send? 
$opts = array(
              'http'=>array(
                'method'=>"GET",
                'header'=>"Authorization: FOOO\r\n".
                    "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
              )
            );
It has only cookie in the header and not authorization

Answer (score 0):

Use a packet sniffer like Wireshark and look for HTTP protocol.

Comment: It's the server that will make the request, so browser dev tools won't help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the server component, you could use [`apache_request_headers`](http://php.net/apache_request_headers) (in case of Apache HTTPD) or inspect `$_SERVER` for keys beginning with `HTTP_`.

Otherwise, you could pass your request through a local HTTP proxy, or run a transport packet analyzer like `tcpdump` or Wireshark on your local machine.